# Continue statements

Tags: language-agnostic, loops

Wondering what a `continue` statement does in a `do...while(false)` loop, I mocked up a simple test-case (pseudo-code):

```
count = 0;
do {
    output(count);
    count++;
    if (count < 10)
        continue;
}while (false);

output('out of loop');
```

The output was, to my surprise:

```
0
out of loop
```

A bit confused, I changed the loop from a `do...while` to a `for`:

```
for (count = 0; count == 0; count++) {
    output(count);
    if (count < 10)
        continue;
}
output('out of loop');
```

While functionally not the same, the purpose is practically the same: Make a condition only satisfied the first iteration, and in next ones continue (until a certain value is reached, purely for stopping possible infinite-loops.) They might not run the same amount of times, but functionality here isn't the important bit.

The output was the same as before:

```
0
out of loop
```

Now, put into terms of a simple `while` loop:

```
count = 0;
while (count == 0) {
    output(count);
    count++;
    if (count < 10)
        continue;
}
output('out of loop');
```

Once again, same output.

This is a bit confusing, as I've always thought of the `continue` statement as "jump to the next iteration". So, here I ask: What does a `continue` statement do in each of these loops? Does it just jump to the condition?

((For what it's worth, I tested the above in JavaScript, but I believe it's language-agnostic...js had to get at least that right))

Comment: @Brad & @Neil: Neil is correct re: my goof up. I shot myself in the foot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a for loop, continue runs the 3rd expression of the for statement (usually used as some kind of iteration), then the condition (2nd expression), and then the loop if the condition is true.  It does not run the rest of the current iteration of the loop.

In a while (or do-while) loop, it just runs the condition and then the loop if the condition holds.  It also does not run the rest of the current iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `continue` statement as "jump to the next iteration" is correct. This will force the program to start next iteration by *first re-evaluating the conditional expression*.

The problem with your snippets is that they all exit after one iteration because your conditional expressions are set to either `false` or `count ==0`. This will always return false after one iteration.

Moreover, putting continue statement at the end of the loop is meaningless. It will re-evaluate the conditional expression in either case.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to think of `continue` as jumping to the end of the enclosing loop. This may haelp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n = 0;

    do {
        cout << n << endl;
        n += 1;
        if ( n == 3 ) {
            continue;
        }
        cout << "n was not 3" << endl;
    } while( n != 3 );

}
```

which prints:

```
0
n was not 3
1
n was not 3
2
```

and terminates, because the continue jumps to the while() at the end of the loop. similar stiff happens for for() and while() loops.

Answer (score 0):

`continue` skips to the next iteration when it is used in a loop. `break` exits the current block. Typically, break is used to exit a loop but it could be used to exit any block.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  if (some_condition) {
    continue; // would skip to the next iteration
  }

  if (some_other_condition) {
    break; // Exits the loop (block)
  }

  // other work
}
```